# Magento 1 : mysql-4 upgrade script is not working

Tags: magento

Magento 1.9.3 - I created a custom module for add attributes in customer account.
Since last one year I am upgrading using same module but now when I am trying to upgrade mysql4-upgrade-0.1.9-0.2.0.php it's not working.

1. core_resource database version is 0.1.9
2. Cache i have already cleared
3. Same upgrade script is working on development server

Comment: Can you update your question with the config.xml and the upgrade script?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. Due to the cache problem new version was not updating but after clear cache multiple times it's working.